# JQuery sortable with centered elements?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using JQuery sortable for some divs.

The divs are centered inside their parent-div with the css-rules "`margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`"

The problem: When I drag an element it jumps to the left side, because the margin doesn't work anymore.

Here's a fiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/annam/35MC3/28/

How can I solve it, so that the element always keeps centered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ddymf/

Add an extra container that centers the items so the sortables don't need to be aligned.

```
<div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="draggable"></div>
        <div class="draggable"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
#outerContainer {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
}
#container {
    width: 100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 10px auto;
    cursor: move;
}
```